# How to dock listbox to a textbox overlapping other items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I am trying to make textbox with autocomplete drop-down listbox.

The problem lies in that there is not space for listbox, as there are other items just below the textbox. Although, not seen on screenshot, the space between textbox and button will be filled with table.

Is there a way to dock or align a listbox to the bottom of given textbox, regardless to other items in layout?

[image]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtb_name"></TextBox>


    <Grid Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btn_givecancel" Content="Cancel" Height="70" FontSize="18.667" Click="btn_givecancel_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btn_giveaccept" Content="Accept" Height="70" FontSize="18.667" Click="btn_giveaccept_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: 2 pieces of advice. Firstly, use a pre-built control if available. Secondly, either use a Popup window or use RowSpan/ColSpan to draw over other controls.

Comment: I don't get the difference between an overlapped standalone listbox and textbox dropdownlist. There are some option in autocomplete you may take a look.

Comment: @Qeeet: What height do you want/expect the `ListBox` to have?

Answer (score 0):

Here's My Implementation:

[image: SuggestTextBox]

Have a Converter that takes Total possible auto suggest item count and current view count:

```
<local:IntToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IntToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Then here's is the Form with TextBox, ListBox and the Button controls.

```
<Grid Margin="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding UserText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="55" ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestionsFiltered, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Canvas.ZIndex="1">
            <ListBox.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="MaxCount"/>
                    <Binding Path="SuggestionsFiltered.Count"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ListBox.Visibility>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 50 0 0">
            <Button Height="20" Width="100">Clear</Button>
            <Button Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10 0 0 0">Accept</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Finally, here's my DataContext:

```
public class TheDataContext
    {
        public TheDataContext()
        {
            FillData();

            _SuggestionsFiltered = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_SuggestionSource);
            _SuggestionsFiltered.Filter = obj =>
            {
                var opt = obj as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_UserText) || _UserText.Length == 0)
                    return true;

                return string.Join("", opt.Take(_UserText.Length)) == _UserText;
            };
        }

        private void FillData()
        {
            _SuggestionSource = new List<string>();
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Alpha");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Alpines");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Bravo");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Brood");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Charlie");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Charles");
            _SuggestionSource.Add("Charlotte");
        }

        private string _UserText;

        public string UserText
        {
            get => _UserText;
            set
            {
                _UserText = value;
                _SuggestionsFiltered.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private List<string> _SuggestionSource;

        public int MaxCount => _SuggestionSource.Count;

        private ICollectionView _SuggestionsFiltered;

        public ICollectionView SuggestionsFiltered
        {
            get => _SuggestionsFiltered;
        }
    }
```

Notice all the code around ICollectionView. Also, I have forcefully set some margins in xaml to show case that Listbox is drawn over other controls (courtsey ZIndex).

If you take this code, remember to handle selected event on ListBox, then set the textBox Text to this value. Also hide the listbox. Bit of a jugglery there.

Lastly, here is the Converter, if you are interested:

```
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int maxCount = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
            int count = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);

            if (count > 0 && count != maxCount)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```